# Angularjs download files problem connecting to server

Tags: angularjs

[image]

This is the returned value from the back-end.

```
viewApp.controller('perInfor',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){

$scope.viewPerson = function(id){
    console.log(id);
    $http({
        method:'get',
        url:'/read?id=' + id
    })
    .then((function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $scope.personalData = response.data.personalDetail;
    
        $scope.applicanID = response.data.vf_id;
        console.log( $scope.applicanID );  
        $scope.documents = response.data.ic;
        //console.log( $scope.documents);
        for(let files in  $scope.documents) {
            //console.log(files, $scope.documents[files]);
            console.log($scope.documents[files].name);
            
        }
        
    })
    )
}
```

This is my controller, I have got the file name, I hope someone can help me how to download these files with Angularjs.

```
<div ng-click="downloadFile('$scope.documents[files].url','contract')">
```

This is my html, it works, but when i click this button, it tells me

> failed, there is a problem connecting to the server.

### downloadFile function code

```
$scope.downloadFile = function (url, filename) {
    saveData(url, filename);
}

function saveData(url, fileName) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

Comment: Check your Network tab if you are getting any response on your request, seems there is some problem with request  Url.

Comment: At this moment, it looks like a URL problem.

Comment: For help with  problems with the `$scope.downloadFile` function, the question needs to include the code for that function.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I share it.

Comment: Why does the code invoke `URL.revokeObjectURL`? What is the URL that has the problem? ObjectURLs can't be retreived with `$http.get` requests. They need to be created using the [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `$scope` in AngularJS expressions:

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> <div ng-click="downloadFile('$scope.documents[files].url','contract')">
> ```

BETTER

```
<div ng-repeat="file in documents">
    <div ng-click="downloadFile(file.url, file.name)">
        {{file.name}} {{file.url}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I try this, but still, don't work. Maybe, it is url problem